# MVC Joining many 2 many tables and filling list based on result in c#

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am doing a school project and need help with this last problem I am having.

Currently I am trying to do a many 2 many join and then fill an IEnumerable list with the result - using linq and lambda.

The purpose is to show the compatible games along with every product.

My code as of now:

```
else
        {

            var result = (from g in db.Games
                            join gs in db.GameSize
                            on g.GameId equals gs.GameId
                            join s in db.Size
                            on gs.SizeId equals s.SizeId
                            join p in db.Product
                            on s.SizeId equals p.SizeId
                          select p.Size.Name);

            games = db.Games
               .Where(game => game.GameSize
               .All(s => s.Size.Name == result.FirstOrDefault()));

        }
```

My idea is to join through the tables and find the gameid who have a matching productid - and then add them to "games".

I am aware that this table design is horrible and that I am only getting the first result in the list with FirstOrDefault().

Does anyone have a suggestion or solution to help me? Thanks.

Please ask if I am not making any sense.

Essentially I just wan't to show the games linked to a size. My table looks like this:

```
--SIZE
insert into size values ('Large')
insert into size values ('Medium')
insert into size values ('Small')

--GAMES
insert into games values ('Magic The Gathering')
insert into games values ('Pokemon')
insert into games values ('Dead of Winter')

--GAMESIZE (RELATION GAMES AND SIZE) (SIZEID, GAMEID)
insert into gamesize values (1, 1)
insert into gamesize values (2, 2)
insert into gamesize values (2, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should really move on from the LINQ to SQL syntax. The EF syntax is much easier and readable. For example:

```
var result = db.Games.Include("GameSize.Size.Product").Select(m => m.Size.Name);
```

Second, `All` doesn't do what you seem to think it does. It returns a boolean: true if all the items match the condition, false if not. It's very unlikely that all your `GameSize`s have the same `Size.Name`. You might be looking for `Any` here.

Third, this whole thing seems counter-intuitive. You're getting all the games and selecting all the size names. Then using that list of size names, to select games that have those size names. In other words, you're doing an extra query to get the results you already had. Remove the select from the `result` and use that for `games` instead.

Long and short, if I'm understanding your code properly, you can reduce all of this to just one simple line:

```
games = db.Games.Include("GameSize.Size.Product");
```

Comment: This gives me kindof the same result. It prints out all the games in the database on every product instead of the ones that are related to the specific product.

Comment: Well, I'm mostly guessing at what these entities look like, but you'd just need add a where clause to restrict to a particular product: `db.Games.Include(...).Where(m => m.GameSize.Size.Product.Id == productId)`. In other words, you've got all the data, so just filter it however you need to to only include the games you're looking for.

Comment: The problem I am having is that i can't make this .Where - it won't let me compare a game or size with product. I successfully made something similar that adds the correct game to a product with an user input `if (size != null)
            {
                games = db.Games
                   .Where(game => game.GameSize
                   .All(s => s.Size.Name
                    == size));
            }`

Comment: While you're at it, post your entities as well. Trying to figure out what queries you need to make without visibility into your object graph is basically impossible.

Comment: Here is my classes: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/pfiqrmfdqql4meo/AAAPG440quupbqGsty0ZKO8ma?dl=0

Comment: Do you have any idea to what the problem might be? I'm using a simple foreach loop to iterate through products and then games in my view.